# Hunchentoot function timeout?

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I'm about to start writing an app that will be accepting uploads of large files. I want to make sure that Hunchentoot doesn't timeout if the upload takes longer than 'X' number of seconds.  I searched quickdocs and found the following instances of timeout:

- *DEFAULT-CONNECTION-TIMEOUT*    / appears to be a socket timeout
- READ-TIMEOUT / may be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure.
- WRITE-TIMEOUT / don't think this is what I want

Would READ-TIMEOUT be the place to start, or is there something that I'm missing?

Thanks!